# Remove new message icon in android

Tags: android, icons, message

I am developing an android appliation that marks SMS messages as read when it is received. I do that using this code:

```
   if(readMessages.contains(id)){
                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put("read", 1);
                values.put("seen", 1);
                getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), 
                        values, "_id="+id, null);
                Log.i("read message","id:"+id);

                if(readThread.contains(trdid)){

                    ContentValues values1=new ContentValues();
                    values1.put("read", 1);
                    values1.put("seen", 1);
                    getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), 
                            values, "_id="+trdid, null);
                    Log.i("read thread","id:"+trdid);

                }
            }
```

As you can see, I've marked the thread and message id's as READ, and the message is indeed marked as read.

My question however is, why doesnt the icon on the messaging app (the red bubble showing the number of new messages) dissappear after I execute the code? Is it possible to do that?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why doesnt the icon on the messaging app (the red bubble showing the number of new messages) dissappear after I execute the code? Is it possible to do that?

You cannot control the notifications from an app that is not your own. Additionally, AOSP messaging does not have red bubble notifications, so this is some custom app.

Regardless of that though, you can't control the notification status of a third party app. It should be the responsibility of the SMS client to update its UI and notifications when a change in the SMS database takes place.

Comment: I use Android 2.3 and the messaging does indeed show a red bubble. Anyway, the bottom line is that it cant be done. Message received!